# How do I package and add my Python app to my launchpad repository?

Tags: python, ubuntu, package, launchpad

I have a launchpad account and an activated ppa but I have no idea how to package my app and upload. I write programs with Python using Tkinter. May someone explain ?

Comment: You need to show that you've put some effort in yourself.  What have you tried?  Where have you looked?  Do you have any sample code from your attempts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to package your project into a .deb. Here's a good tutorial:

https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging

And here is an example packaged app which has TKinter as a dependency:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-pil.imagetk

Snippet from its `control` file:

```
Source: pillow
Section: python
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
XSBC-Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Build-Depends: debhelper, tk-dev, dpkg-dev (>= 1.16.1~),
  python-all-dev (>= 2.7.3-11~), python-all-dbg, python-setuptools,
  python3-all-dev (>= 3.3), python3-all-dbg, python3-setuptools,
  python-tk, python-tk-dbg, python3-tk, python3-tk-dbg (>= 3.3),
  libsane-dev, libfreetype6-dev, libjpeg8-dev, zlib1g-dev, liblcms2-dev,
  libwebp-dev
Build-Conflicts: python-numarray
Standards-Version: 3.9.5
XS-Testsuite: autopkgtest
```

Comment: Where do I put my source file or standalone executable file ? The tutorial doesn't tell anything about where will I put my programs files. I'm not good at theese things, where am I supposed to put my .py or standalone file(doesn't matter which, but standalone package needs to be distributed with a bunch of files in a folder. I used cxfreeze to create it) ?

Comment: You'll likely need setuptools or similar to package your for the python way. FYI: Google keywords: python Debian packaging

Comment: Ok I solved that problem, but I have a problem with my changelog file. What is the format of the changelog file ?